# Windows 10 Octave 3.2.4 not running .m files

Tags: windows, octave

I'm trying to work my way through the Stanford open machine learning course and it requires me to run a `.m` file called `submit1.m`

I have this file and i have made sure i am in the correct directory.

When i try to run this file and submit my answer example - `submit1.m(eye(5,5)`

I receive this error message:

> error: `submit1' undefined near line 9 column 1

Sorry in advance if I'm missing something really simple but I am a completely new to octave.

I have search for an answer on many forums but none of the given solutions are working for me.

If any more information is required please ask and i will do my best.

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE:
I have re-installed Octave and have now got it working at least periodically.
Still not sure what the issue is but at least i have managed to submit my anwser. If anyone can shed some light on what they think the issue might be/have been that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the file "submit1.m" contains a function "submit1" you have to call it with `submit1(eye(5,5))` and not with file extension as you've tried above. Btw. Octave 4.2.0 is released, please install it